# PostgreSQL: column "rolcatupdate" does not exist error?

Tags: postgresql, psql, navicat

I installed PostgreSQL on new server.

When I try create new table or new data base, get this error:

> column "rolcatupdate" does not exist.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

What client/framework are you using for creating a table?

In Postgres 9.5 *"rolcatupdate"* is not anymore supported (list of *pg_roles*: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html)

It might be that some client(s)/framework(s) still use it.

From the [ChangeLog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html):

> Remove the pg_authid catalog's rolcatupdate field, as it had no usefulness (Adam Brightwell)

Comment: I not sure that I understand you about client/framework.
I am use with navicat